# Matching a pattern up until the next instance of that pattern

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to create a Regex to match entries in an SSH configuration file, which has the following basic structure:

```
Host <Name>
    Field1 Value1
    FieldN ValueN
Host *
    Field1 Value1
    FieldN ValueN
Host !<name>
    Field1 Value1
    FieldN ValueN
```

Notes about this structure:
Indentation is optional (I was first using \s in my pattern until I realized this). More details here: https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/

Where there can be any number of hosts (and parameters/fields per host) in a given SSH configuration file. I am struggling to come up with the correct syntax that will capture all cases, and group things appropriately so I can easily handle them in my parsing code.

It seems that, due to the indentation being optional, the "pseudocode" of the pattern is basically:

Match a line that has Host followed by whitespace and then any valid hostname characters, plus ! and/or *, ending in a newline so:

```
(Host\s[a-zA-Z0-9-!\*]+)\n)
```

And then match any subsequent lines, where anything before whitespace is the Field Name and anything after the first occurence of whitespace is the value for that field, UP UNTIL the next instance of a "Host . . . " line, at which point it should be it's own separate match. I have looked into using a few different flags or operators to accomplish this last part but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to make it work, or if something like this is even possible.

An alternative idea would be to scrap regex altogether and write a custom parser for the file, iterating line by line and tracking each host's options, but regex would be ideal as the file that is being passed to my function may or may not even be an SSH configuration file, the code is intended to confirm whether or not it is, and if so, parse the relevant data.

Any guidance on the regex would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can get the index of each occurrence, and then slice the string into several substrings based on these indices

Comment: After a quick Google search, it seems there are multiple open source go packages for reading and manipulating ssh config files

Answer (score 0):

You should not use to it a regular expressions. It probably will complicate your solution and make it so hard to modify. Humans created special type of software called `Parsers` to solve this kind of problems, you described.

See an example here: https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2014/parsers-lexers/

You can find more examples in this repo: https://github.com/danistefanovic/build-your-own-x , just search for the `Parser` word.

If you are sure, you want to do it with regex, you need to split it to steps and first group your hosts then parse them separately one by one. To split them, see example regex: https://regex101.com/r/NFbGxR/1

Comment: Using `[^Host]` in the regex `Host\s+(.*)\n((?:[^Host].*\n)+)?`  means match any single character except for `H` `o` `s` or `t` and will not match if the field for example starts with an `o`

Comment: I know that, but unfortunately there is no negative look ahead supported in standard go package. So I posted better solution is to use the parser - @Thefourthbird

When you use more complex regex, than the implemented in the standard go package you can use sth like: `Host\s+(.*)\n((?:(?!Host).*\n)+)?` as regex